# Can I make this iteration easier by using a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, numpy, iteration

I'm relatively new to python but I have used loops in previous programs I have made but they were relatively simple. 
I was wondering if there was a method that involved a loop or some other way to make this iteration more concise.

Basically is there a way for me to have a variable called 't' that holds values for t1,t2 and t3 in like a list which is then used in 'eq' and 'der' instead of copying and pasting the same piece of code?

I have already tried to look for an answer on here and other places but the solutions I have found so far don't seem to work with what I have got/I'm not python literate enough to understand them.

```
import numpy as np
U235_Decay_Constant = 9.72e-10
U238_Decay_Constant = 1.54e-10


t0 = 4.1e9


eq = ((np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t0)-1)-(0.0167* 
((np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t0)-1)))-0.0094)
der = (U238_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t0)))-(0.0167* 
(U235_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t0))))

t1 = t0 - (eq/der)


eq = ((np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t1)-1)-(0.0167* 
((np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t1)-1)))-0.0094)
der = (U238_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t1)))-(0.0167* 
(U235_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t1))))

t2 = t1 - (eq/der)

eq = ((np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t2)-1)-(0.0167* 
((np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t2)-1)))-0.0094)
der = (U238_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t2)))-(0.0167* 
(U235_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t2))))

t3 = t2 - (eq/der)
print(t3)
```

Comment: Hey welcome to stackover flow! So basically you want to have a loop that creates the t3 value? You can edit you question to make it easier for us to help ;)

Comment: Glad you found both answers to be of help! However, you can only pick *one* of them to be the 'accepted' answer. The choice is entirely yours, pick one you feel helped you the most perhaps, and picking neither is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a little easier to read as:

```
import numpy as np
U235_Decay_Constant = 9.72e-10
U238_Decay_Constant = 1.54e-10


t = [4.1e9, None, None, None]

t[0] = 4.1e9
for i in range(3):
    eq = ((np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t[i])-1)-(0.0167*
    ((np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t[i])-1)))-0.0094)

    der = (U238_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant*t[0])))-(0.0167*
    (U235_Decay_Constant*(np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant*t[0]))))

    t[i+1] = t[i] - (eq/der)

print(t[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iteration can help here. Add your values to a list, then `t?` is the last value in the list so far; replacing your `t?` references with `t[-1]` gives:

```
t = [4.1e9]
for _ in range(3):
    eq = (
        (np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant * t[-1]) - 1)
        - (0.0167 * ((np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant * t[-1]) - 1)))
        - 0.0094
    )
    der = (U238_Decay_Constant * (np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant * t[-1]))) - (
        0.0167 * (U235_Decay_Constant * (np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant * t[-1])))
    )
    t.append(t[-1] - (eq / der))
```

The general principle is one of *accumulation*, where you produce the running output of a repeated application of a function. So the [`itertools.accumulate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) could help here too:

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain, repeat

def u238_decay(t, _):
    eq = (
        (np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant * t) - 1)
        - (0.0167 * ((np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant * t) - 1)))
        - 0.0094
    )
    der = (U238_Decay_Constant * (np.exp(U238_Decay_Constant * t))) - (
        0.0167 * (U235_Decay_Constant * (np.exp(U235_Decay_Constant * t)))
    )
    return t - (eq / der)

series = accumulate(chain([4.1e9], repeat(None)), u238_decay)
```

The above produces an unending series of decay values:

```
>>> series = accumulate(chain([4.1e9], repeat(None)), u238_decay)
>>> next(series)
4100000000.0
>>> next(series)
4081406102.7439713
>>> next(series)
4081163259.5641546
>>> next(series)
4081163218.6509323
>>> next(series)
4081163218.650931
```

You could look into creating a [numpy universal function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html) so you can do the same with the [`numpy.ufunc.accumulate()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html#numpy.ufunc.accumulate).

However, I suspect that your formula can be re-cast to not depend on the previous input, but only as a formula of starting amount and `t` as time, at which point you can use full numpy vectorised calculations.